# App crash after Activity Changed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest

I have implemented a splash screen to finish after 3 seconds and load up the Main activity, however, it is consistently crashing and saying that the application has stopped.

I though I had successful amended the manifest, however, I'm confident that the problem stems from the manifest itself.

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Very new at Android, apologies if there is any information missing.

Sorry for messy LogCat!

**SplashScreen.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

    public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

            Thread myThread = new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        sleep (3000);
                        Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            myThread.start();
        }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.benf.myapplication">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".SplashScreen"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

**LogCat**

```
    01-30 12:31:37.824 4954-4954/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-30 12:31:38.109 4954-4954/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
01-30 12:31:38.529 4954-4954/com.example.benf.myapplication I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
01-30 12:31:38.939 4954-4981/com.example.benf.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
01-30 12:31:39.040 4954-4981/com.example.bef.myapplication I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
01-30 12:31:39.040 4954-4981/com.example.benf.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-30 12:31:39.040 4954-4981/com.example.benf.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
01-30 12:31:39.041 4954-4981/com.example.benf.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
01-30 12:31:39.041 4954-4981/com.example.benf.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
01-30 12:31:39.046 4954-4981/com.example.benf.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xb060ea60: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
01-30 12:31:39.049 4954-4981/com.example.benf.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb060ea60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8849650)
01-30 12:31:39.177 4954-4981/com.example.benf.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb060ea60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8849650)
01-30 12:31:42.189 4954-4954/com.example.benf.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-30 12:31:42.192 4954-4954/com.example.benf.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.benf.myapplication, PID: 4954
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.benf.myapplication/com.example.benf.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:201)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                                                                                         at com.example.benf.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: check this line: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: Post the code of your `MainActivity`, that is where the crash happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified any theme for MainActivity. You are using toolbar in MainActivity I guess and your application theme is `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` which also provides actionbar. So this situation making conflicts.

In your activity declaration change to this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `MainActivity` class you are trying to add toolbar, this creating problem. Because by this `<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>`
Application theme will be applied in this activity, which you specified inside Application tag `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

This theme itself contains ActionBar also.

Apply theme to your MainActivity like you done for your SplashScreen Activity by,

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify this in your manifest for MainActivity-:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```